# How to pass -v argument to an AWK CGI script called through an URL?

Tags: awk, cgi

I have an AWK script which looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { print myVar; }
{ print; }
```

which I can run locally in a Unix shell via the command

```
./myScript.awk -v myVar=value /tmp/inputfile
```

It correctly prints "value" and then dumps the inputfile.

I set up an apache web server with CGI enabled and created the following myScript.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    print "Content-type: text/plain";
    print "";
    print myVar;
}
{ print; }
```

I can run it by pointing my web browser to

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/myScript.cgi?/tmp/inputfile
```

but how can I pass the "-v myVar=value" bit through the URL?

Comment: Did you try using ?myVar=value on the URL?

Comment: I still want "/tmp/inputfile" to be the there in the argument. I tried adding "myVar=value" there as well, with "+", "&" and "%20" as separators with and without a "-v", but not much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* pass a '-v' variable through the CGI interface. The only way to access information is via a number number of environment variables that the CGI interface sets for you. You can access these in awk through the `ENVIRON` array. You are probably mostly interested in the `QUERY_STRING` variable, so try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    print "Content-type: text/plain"
    print ""
    print ENVIRON["QUERY_STRING"]
}
1
```

When accessed as `http://localhost/cgi-bin/myScript.cgi?myVar=foo&otherVar=bar`,  `ENVIRON["QUERY_STRING"]` will contain `myVar=foo&otherVar=bar`. You will have to process this string yourself to extract your variables. For example (untested):

```
BEGIN {
    split(ENVIRON["QUERY_STRING"], a, "&")
    for (i in a) {
        if (a[i] ~ /^myVar=/) {
            split(a[i], tmp, "=")
            myVar=tmp[2]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That also passes "myVar=foo&otherVar=bar" to "/usr/bin/gawk -f", which is wrong. My script will indeed have the myVar and otherVar arguments, but will not have a stdin source (as the argument passed to -f will result in a file not found).

Comment: @Balint I guess your Apache CGI configuration is unclear to me, the argument to '-f' should only be the cgi-script itself.